# Disable radio button in sap.m.Table sapui5

Tags: sapui5

I am using **sap.m.Table**, I have to make radio buttons disable in that table. How can I disable the radio buttons, so that it should be non-clickable. Here I used **"SingleSelectLeft"** property for the table. Thanks in Advance!

**Here I have sample table-**

```
var table = new sap.m.Table({
    mode: "SingleSelectLeft",
    columns: [
        new sap.m.Column({
            header: new sap.m.Text({
                text: "First Name"
            })
        }),
        new sap.m.Column({
            header: new sap.m.Text({
                text: "Last Name"
            })
        }),
        new sap.m.Column({
            header: new sap.m.Text({
                text: "Email Address"
            })
        })
    ]
});
```

Comment: Raviteja,

I think there is no such property(enabled : false) is there for table. If you can again go through this question I have added line of code now. Here, I used "SingleSelectLeft" mode.

Comment: Have you thought of `mode: "None"` (which is the default btw)?

Comment: @Marc,
By using mode: "None" radio buttons will be hidden. But, I want to keep radio buttons visible for each record and only wants to disable the click on that radio button.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your scenario.. you can just create one more column which contains radio button and make that "enable:false" in defailt mode.